# Try getting full friendlist on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am writing Facebook search engine, so now I need to get all my fb friend's names and ids to an array.

I've already tried with Facebook sdk for .net, some py library, library for java and I always get only one person into my array, I select everything on token's permission. This is always the same person, who is developer too. But there is nobody else.

Is there a way get this with API, or should I start looking at html, and get friendlist from html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't not supply Facebook Friends as of OpenGraph 2.0.

**Please refer to [Using the Graph API.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0)**

You can only get the friends that are using the App, or the friends that are invite-able.

Good Luck!